# Reflection "ghost" when using EEVEE Reflection Plane

Tags: eevee-render-engine, glass, reflection

I'm trying to set up a nice looking partially reflecting glass plane in EEVEE. To test this, I just used a solidified plane, two Suzannes and a reflection plane.[image]
What bothers me is the fact that the Suzanne nearest to the camera is reflected twice: Once seemingly correctly and a second time faintly and about half the expected size. [image]

What am I doing wrong?
(Blender 2.91 on Linux with Nvidia drivers)

Edit: Here's the blendfile: [image]
(Btw. anybody else having problems uploading blendfiles from firefox?)

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Lemon's answer, you have enabled the *Show Backface* option, as your mirror object has thickness, it reflects the blue suzanne on both the front and back face. Just disable this option and you'll see only one reflection. As for the size it's because you've smoothed the object, you can right click and choose *Shade Flat*.

[image]

Comment: Actually, the strange size of the second reflection threw me off the path that would have led to the "show backface" toggle.

And somewhat strangely, apparently the flat shading alone resolves the problem, regardless of backface option.

Anyway - thanks a lot to both repliers!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you consider to be the ghost reflection, you can use one of the following for the glass material:

[image]

Both use *"backfacing"* from the geometry node. To eliminate the ghost, we choose only one reflection (either back or front facing).

On left, the backface is reflective (as front face is transparent).

On right, the backface is transparent (and front is reflective).

0.25 is the alpha value.

Comment: what is the advantage compared to disabling the Show Backface option?

Comment: @moonboots, to tell the truth, I've not though about it... But if an advantage maybe Cycles compatible?

Comment: oh ok yes, I may be wrong but I think the poster didn't realize that he got both the 2 reflections and only want the front one